# Activation of application xxx!App failed with error: Unknown HResult Error code: 0xc0eb0003

Tags: windows-10

I have installed the newly released `Windows 10` and now get the following error message in the Event Viewer when starting a modern app:

> Activation of application Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App failed with error: Unknown HResult Error code: 0xc0eb0003 See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

I can't see the `Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational` log either:

[image]

I saw a [post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_store/apps-crash-with-cant-open-app-error/ad1180b8-127b-4b06-813b-d5ba0f4ea69f) on the Microsoft website about a preview build with this error, but the answer was just to upgrade to the later build.

I have recently installed lots of software ranging from `Gimp` to `SQL Server`, so have no idea what could have caused this. I also disabled `Hyper-V` too so I can use `VMware`

Comment: I received this after I converted my local account to a Microsoft account. Before the apps worked fine. Running RTM.

Comment: This worked for me

http://superuser.com/questions/951256/windows-10-apps-will-not-start

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Set up Win 10 with a clean install, installed some applications and some time later I was not able to open the start menu or edge.

Cortana, Edge and windows shell experience host created a *Activation of application x failed with error* entry in the event log everytime I tried to open one of them.

I ended up deleting and recreating the user which fixed the issue for me, even after I restored the same settings and applications.

Comment: This is probably more of a workaround, than an actual fix.

Answer (score 0):

My computer was on a domain, and I was able to fix the problem by removing the association with my Microsoft account.

I also had problems keeping my windows activated. At each startup, if I checked on the activation status, it always appears as if it was not activated. I was able to trigger the activation by clicking on the "Go to store" button.

I believe the windows activation problem is linked to the windows stop apps failure errors