# Windows 10 apps will not start

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app

Just upgraded my Windows 8.1 Pro (Lenovo W540 laptop) to Windows 10, everything went smoothly, all my settings and installed apps preserved and work without a hitch.

The only issue is - Windows's own apps - Calendar, Mail etc. even Windows AppStore - won't launch. When I run them I very briefly see a window flashing and then nothing happens after that.

Any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

EDIT: Seeing bunch of these in Event log: *Activation of app Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App failed with error: Access is denied. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.*

Comment: Based on the error you have sever permissions problems.  If doing a Refresh which would mean losing your installed applications, I suggest you go back to Windows 8.1, and making sure those permissions problems were not present there also.

Comment: @Ramhound it worked in 8.1 and it worked (for a while in Win10 as well). but you were right that error was a clue, and I found the solution

Comment: This has happened to a lot of people.  People have been complaining about since Windows 10 launched.  I believe this question is a dupe...  but your answer is the best and clearest so far.

Comment: I could not write an answer here because of reputation issue. However, I ran into the same problem where all windows 10 apps did not open. I tried so many options I found online and none worked for. What worked for me eventually was running this in PowerShell: `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` from [here](http://www.itprotoday.com/windows-server/fixing-windows-10-apps-wont-launch-or-hang-apps-splash-screen)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Figured it out](http://codecorner.galanter.net/2015/08/05/solution-windows-10-unable-to-start-appstore-apps/). For some reason `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` account lost access to `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps` folder. Once I added it - problem was solved, appstore apps launch normally.

[image]]

Comment: What?!!! I've searched all day trying to uninstall, reinstall and register Store but not a single webpage said this was the solution.

Comment: With an obvious note that the "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES" account name is language specific, this was the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Also, check registry permissions. See this Microsoft article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2798317

Comment: Can you help me on the Same issue with Windows 10 ?

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me get it started again. Now I just have to repair installing apps...

Comment: In our case the registry key permission where broken: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders