# Why is TWINUI "the best music app for Windows"?

Tags: windows-10, file-association, media-player

Something on my Windows 10 profile seems to be broken. Trying to double-click on an mp3 file yields "Class not registered":

[image: Class not registered]

Selecting "Open with/Choose another app" in the context menu yields:

[image: TWINUI is great]

Checking the default file associations also reveals that TWINUI is "Recommended for Windows 10":

[image: TWINUI is recommended]

Now, I know that I could fix this issue by just choosing Windows Media Player as my default mp3 player, but since I do want to "enjoy all the music I love" (see second screenshot) I'd really like to give TWINUI a chance. Some [websites claim](https://www.slightfuture.com/technote/what-is-twinui) that TWINUI is just an app chooser, but surely they must be mistaken since Windows tells me that TWINUI is the bestest media player of all times.

No, seriously: It looks like some default Metro media player app that should be there is missing. How can I restore it? (I did not install anything from the app store, it's a plain Windows 10.0.14393.187.)

Note: Other apps work fine and I don't have permission errors in my event log, so it's not a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/951256/14517).

Comment: TWINUI is the shell. uninstall groove music and reinstall it via store

Comment: The description of the application, is "the best music app" does not actually mean It is the best music application.  [**You have a permission problem.**](http://superuser.com/questions/951256/windows-10-apps-will-not-start).  The recommended application is not actually TWINUI by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks, but it seems that that answer does not apply. Other apps work fine and I don't have permission errors in my event log. (And about TWINUI and the "best music app" - I thought that the use of "bestest" and "No, seriously" was enough to indicate that the previous sentence was ironic in nature...)

Comment: Did you perhaps forcefully remove system apps?

Comment: @DanielB: Nope.

Comment: @Heinzi Sarcasm belongs at Yahoo Answers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been fixed by upgrading the machine to the current Redstone 2 build (v10.0.14931.1000, now available on the slow insider ring).

Unfortunately, that also means that the reason for this issue might forever remain unknown. It might have been a bug that was fixed, or it might have been a configuration issue fixed as a side-effect of the upgrade.

And another mystery has been solved: The "best music app" is actually called *Groove*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this issue as well. The issue is caused by corrupted or invalid registry key/value pairs.

I found a PowerShell script which fixes the bug and I'm now hosting it on Github at https://github.com/WillBixler/TwinUI-Fix.